# Transferring Base64 string from C# to Python and vice versa

Tags: c#, python, base64

I'm building a project that includes file transferring through sockets. My server is written in python and my client is in C#. Since Python isn't very friendly when it comes to charsets, I'm transferring a file I'm uploading from the client by converting it into base64, and decoding it in python. It works perfectly. For some reason, when I do the opposite, when I encode the text in python and decode after transferring it throws errors.
Have a look - 
This is the correct sending from client to server:

```
List<byte> b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(cont)).ToList();
int size = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(st) + b.Count;
string pack = size + ":" + st;
buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pack);
List<byte> a = buffer.ToList();
a.AddRange(b);
connection.Send(a.ToArray());
```

And python:

```
base64.b64decode(params[2])
```

And this works.
When I do opposite(with the same libraries it makes an error):

```
string res = SendRecv("1?" + basepath + v[0]);
res = res.Remove(res.Length - 1).Substring(1);//because it is sent quoted

byte[] converted = Convert.FromBase64String(res.Replace(" ",String.Empty));
saved.Write(converted, 0, converted.Length);
saved.Close();
```

The SendRecv(send, and recv) methods:

```
    private void Send(string st)
    {
        int size = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(st);
        string pack = size + ":" + st;
        buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pack);
        connection.Send(buffer);
    }
    private string Recv()
    {
        try
        {
            buffer = new byte[2];
            connection.Receive(buffer, 2, SocketFlags.Partial);
            string header = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 2);
            while (!header.Contains(":"))
            {
                connection.Receive(buffer, 2, SocketFlags.Partial);
                header += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 2);
            }
            int size = int.Parse(header.Split(':')[0]);
            string mes0 = header.Split(':')[1];
            buffer = new byte[size];
            int b = 0;
            int s = (size >= 2048) ? 2048 : size;
            while(size-s > 0)
            {
                connection.Receive(buffer,b,s,SocketFlags.None);
                size -= s;
                s = (size >= 2048) ? 2048 : size;
                b += s;
            }
            connection.Receive(buffer, size, SocketFlags.None);
            string fullmes = mes0 + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);


            return fullmes;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        return "";
    }
    private string SendRecv(string a)
    {
        Send(a);
        return Recv();
    }
```

Python:

```
return base64.b64encode(self.finalResult.getContent())
```

And it throws this exception:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters

Comment: What if you print the result of the Python and input it as a string literal in C#?

Comment: Can you show us a portion of res variable, as received by server?